# grails simple redirect not working

Tags: grails, redirect, show

Right, I appear to be doing this right and its so simple there really shouldn't be anything missing but for the life of me I can't see why its not working, I have a remote link on my list view like thus: -

```
<g:remoteLink action="makeReady" id="${testExecQueueInstance.id}">X</g:remoteLink>
```

The makeReady is empty at this point apart from I want it to show the line selected, so the controller only has this in it: -

```
def makeReady(Long myid){
    redirect(action:"show", id:myid)
}
```

And the show action is the bog standard show that grails creates with just a Lond being passed in...

Why isn't this working?  What dumbass obviousness thing have I missed that I'll be kicking myself over for the next few days?

Comment: what is the actual error that is occurring? Is a redirect happening to the wrong url? Is the Ajax call not being made? Is the makeReady controller action not being executed?

Comment: Nothing was actually happening at all unfortunately... :(

Comment: So, even Ajax call is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`<g:remoteLink` makes ajax request, and your page is already rendered, server can't make redirect from it, it's already displayed.

There are two ways to make it working:

- use standard link
- respond with a JSON/Javascript, and make redirection on client side.

For second option it's going to be something like:

```
<div id="success"></div>
<g:remoteLink action="makeReady" id="${testExecQueueInstance.id}" update="success">X</g:remoteLink>
```

and

```
def makeReady(Long myid){
  String url = createLink(action:"show", id:myid)
  render(text: "window.location.href='${url.encodeAsURL()}'", contentType: "application/javascript")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Igor, but when i try this i get this error "ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FARTFramework/testExecQueue/makeReady/10
No signature of method: java.lang.String.encodeAsJavascript() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: java.lang.String.encodeAsJavascript() is applicable for argument types: () values: []"

Comment: You're right, should be `.encodeAsJavaScript()` instead. Or `.encodeAsURL()`

Comment: When I change it to encodeasURL I get a redirect but its not loading a proper page, the URL that is generated now looks to read "localhost/framework/testExecQueue/%2Fframework/%2FtestExecQueue/%Fshow" with no id, not sure whats happening here...?

Comment: And if I try with .encodeAsJavaScript then the div quickly shows the text "window.location.href='\/framework\/testExecQueue\/show'" before the list page just refreshes with a message at the top reading "TestExecQueue not found with id null" ?

Comment: It's hard to understand why it generates invalid URL on your end, w/o extra details (complete code, etc). And it looks like another question

Comment: What other code would you need to help debug?  I've only used the code you provided above and haven't added anything else in so I'm at a loss...

Comment: In the head I currently have this <g:javascript library="jquery" />  should I have something different or change the syntax to deal with it in a different way because of this?

Comment: How you build a link on server side? createLink? does it work on other places?

Comment: A generic link?  I can use a g:link with the action and ID and that works ok (like with any of the list views which automatically turn the first column into links to the show actions...)

Comment: so, `link` generates tag with correct url, but `createLink` with same parameters generates invalid url, right?

Comment: Sorry no, I can't get that to work either, but what I've done in the end to get round to this was to do the following, which seems to work though I have no idea how I'm not questioning it haha!  Thanks for your help Igor it was much appreciated!

`def testExecQueueInstance = TestExecQueue.get(id)
testExecQueueInstance.properties = params
redirect(action: "list")`